# jQuery and labels

Tags: jquery, html

Further to my previous question, I have a jQuery event that I want to fire when the checkbox *and* the label itself is clicked.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/pqWPX/) example here.

My problem is that when I click the label, it doesn't fire the function. The checkbox works fine, as you can see.

Is there anything more I can add? Or is this it?

Thanks :)

---

*EDIT: code from jsFiddle link*

HTML

```
<div id="scrollwrap">
    <div>
       <input value="1"  type="checkbox" name="salgsvilkar" id="checkbox2"  style="float:left;"/>
        <label for="checkbox2" class="akslabel">Salgs og leveringsvilkår er lest og akseptert</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    //checkbox
    $("#checkbox2, .akslabel").click(function() {
        $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it a bit like this to be safe:

```
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox2").change(function(){
    $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gqwcC/).  The advantage here is you can add a [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on the end to make the state match if it's initially checked, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox2").change(function(){
    $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gqwcC/1/).  You can also make this *much* more generic, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gqwcC/2/).

Comment: Great, the second version is exactly what I was trying to accomplish! Thanks again, Nick. Is there anything that jQuery can't do?

Comment: @Kyle - unfortunately it doesn't cook the waffles, that part is manual

Comment: It can't make you applepie...But it can make you a nice pie-chart with the right plugins :)

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
$(function() {
   //checkbox
   $("#checkbox2").change(function(){
    $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

The reason it didn't work when you had `click()` is because clicking on the label triggers the event twice since it is attached to both elements - which means it will toggle the class name twice!

Comment: Be aware that on some browsers (read: IE) the onchange event of a checkbox is fired only after it loses focus, not at the time of the click itself.